# 開発環境をDocker、本番環境をAWS EC2にする際のファイル構成について

Tags: php, aws, docker, laravel

最近AWSを触り始めたのですが、今までクラウドサーバーを触る機会がなくGitへどこまで登録するべきか悩んでいます。
開発環境をDockerで構築し、本番環境はECRを用いずEC2で構築しようと考えています。
現在のファイル構成は以下のような形です。

```
App
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker 
│   ├── php 
│   │   ├── Dockerfile 
│   │   └── php.ini 
│   └── nginx 
│       └── default.conf 
├── phpMyAdmin
└── src 
    └──  LaravelProject
```

EC2内で`git pull`プルした場合に`/var/www`配下にsrc以下が配置されないため、
EC2でデプロイする場合はDocker情報などはGitに登録せず、src配下のみ登録するのが一般的でしょうか？
それともEC2上でDockerを立ち上げて公開するのが一般的でしょうか？

質問がわかり辛く申し訳ありませんが、回答いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

開発環境として疎な環境を使うためでDockerを利用したいと読み取りました。
「開発環境での評価対象」はコンテナから外すのがいいかと思います。

逆にミドルウェアの設定などは、開発環境でもVMで持っておかないと、再現テストとかで苦労しそうだし、本番のデリバリ手順やデリバリシステム構築に支障がありそうですね。

開発からサービスイン、その後の保守まで含めて検討する必要があります。

私の感覚ではlalabelのプロジェクトは「開発環境」ではないので、外だしして管理するのがいいのかなと思います。
テスト時のインテグは、CI/CDパイプラインでやればいいので。
この場合もDockerのイメージの中に入れるよりは、volumesで外だししたパスに投げこむほうがいいのかなと思います。＜最終配布形態がdockerではないので。dockerコンテナをテストする利点が薄いのです。